# huge amount of whitespace on right side of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys I've ran into this problem before and posted it on this site. I was recommended overflow-x: hidden to solve the problem. This works for the most part but then i noticed even with that property there's like a 10px scroll still. Now for the most part of this project that wasn't the case it just recently started happening so I took the property off so I could view all of the whitespace whith my dev tools but could't find anything sticking out on the right. Why is this happening? Appreciate the help:)

p.s I have to post some code to post this link for some reason, but its just the html click the link for all my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>El Metate | Mexican Food</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Kumar+One+Outline|Teko" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Diplomata+SC|Ewert|Sarina|Smokum" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="nav-btn">
    <div class="btn-1"></div>
    <div class="btn-2"></div>
    <div class="btn-3"></div>
   </div> 
    <div class="side-menu">
     <ul>
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hours">Hours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   <p><span class="auth">Authentic</span><span class="mexi">Mexican</span><span class="food">Food</span></p>
   <img src="img/LogoMakr_Oso9xi.png" alt="">
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="about">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <h1>About us</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, quis, adipisci! Unde natus quas officiis, earum commodi! Voluptate in modi alias quisquam maiores sunt fugit reprehenderit odio rem obcaecati libero repellat saepe quidem quibusdam impedit labore error velit, possimus necessitatibus. Optio ullam, officiis, sit ipsa fugiat animi voluptas labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, et.</p>
   <div class="image-slider">
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down left"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="menu">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="left-border">
    <div class="shape-wrap">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 2310px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="right-border">
    <div class="shape-wrap">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 385px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 770px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1155px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1540px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 1925px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 2310px;">
     <span class="shape-1"></span>
     <span class="shape-2"></span>
     <span class="shape-3"></span>
     <span class="shape-4"></span>
     <span class="shape-5"></span>
     <span class="shape-6"></span>
     <span class="shape-7"></span>
     <span class="shape-8"></span>
     <span class="shape-9"></span>
     <span class="shape-10"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

   <h1>Menu</h1>
   <div class="line-2"></div>

   <div class="vexel-images"></div>

   <div class="col-1">
    <h3 class="platter">Combination Platters</h3>
    <p class="platter-info">Rice & Beans Included</p>

    <p class="item item-1">Tostada & Taco</p><span class="price p1"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-2">2 Beef Tacos</p><span class="price p2"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-3">2 Enchiladas</p><span class="price p3"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-4">Tostada & Enchilada</p><span class="price p4"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-5">Taco & Enchilada</p><span class="price p5"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-6">Burrito & Enchilada</p><span class="price p6"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-7">2 Beef Burritos</p><span class="price p7"><span class="s1">$</span>7.45</span>
    <p class="item item-8">2 Carne Asada Tacos</p><span class="price p8"><span class="s1">$</span>8.09</span>
    <p class="item item-9">Chorizo</p><span class="price p9"><span class="s1">$</span>6.39</span>
    <p class="item item-10">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p10"><span class="s1">$</span>8.19</span>
    <p class="item item-11">Machaca</p><span class="price p11"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
    <p class="item item-12">Carnitas</p><span class="price p12"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
    <p class="item item-13">2 Fish Tacos</p><span class="price p13"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
    <p class="item item-14">Chiles Rellenos</p><span class="price p14"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
    <p class="item item-15">Red Combo</p><span class="price p15"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span>
    <p class="item item-16">Green Combo</p><span class="price p16"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
    <p class="item item-17">3 Rolled Tacos w/Guacamole</p><span class="price p17"><span class="s1">$</span>6.75</span>
    <p class="item item-18">Chimichanga, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p18"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>
    <p class="item item-19">Carne Asada Burrito</p><span class="price p19"><span class="s1">$</span>7.19</span>
    <p class="item item-20">2 Tamales, Rice & Beans</p><span class="price p20"><span class="s1">$</span>7.05</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-4">Tacos</h3>
    <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Folded</p>

    <p class="item item-21">1 Chicken Taco</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">1 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-23">1 Carne Asada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
    <p class="item item-21">1 Fish</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-22">1 Carnitas</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">1 Adobada</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">1 Cabeza</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

    <p class="platter-info info4tacos">Rolled</p>

    <p class="item item-21">3 Plain with Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.39</span>
    <p class="item item-22">3 Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
    <p class="item item-23">3 Chicken w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.89</span>
    <p class="item item-21">3 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>3.99</span>
    <p class="item item-22">12 Tacos w/Cheese and Guacamole</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>8.99</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-7">Tortas</h3>

    <p class="item item-21">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Machaca</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.09</span>
    <p class="item item-23">Ham</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.61</span>
    <p class="item item-21">Chorizo</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chicken</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">Carnitas</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>
    <p class="item item-23">Fish</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>2.64</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-8">Breakfast Served Everyday</h3>
    <p class="platter-info info4breakfast">6am to 11am</p>

    <h3 class="platter plat-9">Breakfast Plates</h3>
    
    <p class="item item-21">Huevos Racheros</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>6.29</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Steaks Racheros</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Suasage</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chorizo Omelette</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>6.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Carne Asada Omelette</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>7.95</span><p class="item item-22">Scrambled Eggs w/Ham</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Eggs and Bacon</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>5.95</span>
   </div>

   <div class="col-2">
    <h3 class="platter plat-2">Enchiladas</h3>

    <p class="item item-21">2 Cheese</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-22">2 Beef</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-23">2 Chicken</p><span class="price p23"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-3">Side Orders</h3>

    <p class="item item-24">Carne Asada Fries</p><span class="price p24"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-25">Jalepenos</p><span class="price p25"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-26">Quesadilla</p><span class="price p26"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-27">Ham Quesadilla</p><span class="price p27"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-28">1/2 Pint of Beans</p><span class="price p28"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-29">1/2 Pint of rice</p><span class="price p29"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-30">Ham Quesadilla</p><span class="price p30"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-31">Super Nachos</p><span class="price p31"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-32">1 Tamale</p><span class="price p32"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-33">Extra Cheese Quacamole</p><span class="price p33"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-34">Supreme Quesadilla</p><span class="price p34"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-35">Chips and Quacamole</p><span class="price p35"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-36">1 Chiles Rellano</p><span class="price p36"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-37">Chips & Salsa</p><span class="price p37"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Churros</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Burrito Asada R&B</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.55</span>
    <p class="item item-40">1/2 Pint of Beans</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.65</span>
    <p class="item item-41">1/2 Pint of rice</p><span class="price p41"><span class="s1">$</span>3.55</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-5">Tostadas</h3>

    <p class="item item-38">Beef</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>2.85</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Chicken</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>2.85</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Bean</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>2.49</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-6">Burritos</h3>

    <p class="item item-38">Red Chili</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.49</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Carne Asada</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.90</span>
    <p class="item item-40">California</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.90</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Machaca</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Mixed</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Beef</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Chicken</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Beans</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>1.90</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Fish</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Carnitas</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Chimichanga</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>5.85</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Chile Relleno</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>4.49</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Adobada</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.19</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Green Chile</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.49</span>
    <p class="item item-40">Shrimp</p><span class="price p40"><span class="s1">$</span>5.65</span>
    <p class="item item-38">Cabeza</p><span class="price p38"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>
    <p class="item item-39">Pollo Asado</p><span class="price p39"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>

    <h3 class="platter plat-10">Breakfast Burritos</h3>
    
    <p class="item item-21">Suasage & Egg</p><span class="price p21"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Ham & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Bacon & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Steak & Chorizon</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.75</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Picodegallo eggs & cheese</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>3.95</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chorizo & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.85</span>
    <p class="item item-22">Chorizo & Eggs</p><span class="price p22"><span class="s1">$</span>4.09</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="hours">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: 250px; left: 70px;">
    <span class="shape-1"></span>
    <span class="shape-2"></span>
    <span class="shape-3 move3"></span>
    <span class="shape-4"></span>
    <span class="shape-5"></span>
    <span class="shape-6"></span>
    <span class="shape-7"></span>
    <span class="shape-8"></span>
    <span class="shape-9"></span>
    <span class="shape-10 move10"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="shape-wrap rotate" style="top: 543px; left: -240px;">
    <span class="shape-1"></span>
    <span class="shape-2"></span>
    <span class="shape-3 move3"></span>
    <span class="shape-4"></span>
    <span class="shape-5"></span>
    <span class="shape-6"></span>
    <span class="shape-7"></span>
    <span class="shape-8"></span>
    <span class="shape-9"></span>
    <span class="shape-10 move10"></span>
   </div>
   <h1>Hours</h1>
   <div class="hours-line"></div>
   <div class="hours-line2"></div>

   <div class="grid">
    <div class="day">Sunday</div>
    <div class="hour">8am - 8pm</div>
    <div class="day">Monday</div>
    <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
    <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
    <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
    <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
    <div class="day">Thursday</div>
    <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
    <div class="day">Friday</div>
    <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
    <div class="day">Saturday</div>
    <div class="hour">6am - 10am</div>
   </div>

   <div class="shape-wrap" style="top: -470px; left: 980px;">
    <span class="shape-1"></span>
    <span class="shape-2"></span>
    <span class="shape-3 move3"></span>
    <span class="shape-4"></span>
    <span class="shape-5"></span>
    <span class="shape-6"></span>
    <span class="shape-7"></span>
    <span class="shape-8"></span>
    <span class="shape-9"></span>
    <span class="shape-10 move10"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="shape-wrap lom" style="top: -175px; left: -90px;">
    <span class="shape-1"></span>
    <span class="shape-2"></span>
    <span class="shape-3 move3"></span>
    <span class="shape-4"></span>
    <span class="shape-5"></span>
    <span class="shape-6"></span>
    <span class="shape-7"></span>
    <span class="shape-8"></span>
    <span class="shape-9"></span>
    <span class="shape-10 move10"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4h52f3w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to `#hours, #menu` to fix it.

The problem is that the clip-path is making the children of them bigger and positioned weirdly.

Comment: Thanks dude your a real one:)